# SAPUI5 list/combobox data binding replacing with a table

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have to replace a data binding from a list (combobox) with a table. Its important that we add the filter to have a right data binding in the combobox. oInput is defined as a combobox:

```
            oInput.setModel(oView.getModel());
            oInput.bindAggregation("items", "/shrhelpSet", oTemplete);

            oFilterObject = new sap.ui.model.Filter("object", "EQ", that.g_object);
            oFilterField = new sap.ui.model.Filter("field", "EQ",
                that.g_TechNameArr[i]);
            oFilterLang = new Filter("lang", "EQ", sCurrentLocale);
            oFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilterObject, oFilterField, oFilterLang], true);

            oInput.getBinding("items").filter(oFilters);
```

My problem is how i can replace it to a binding with a table. I am using a sap.ui.table in a ValueHelpDialog. I have fixed column data which i definded in an array, and now i need to add the data from the  list binding to a array for the row binding. i defined a array "aData" where i have to put the data of the dataset /shrhelpSet with a filter. I tried it with

```
    //var aData = this.getModel().getData("/shrhelpSet").filter(oFilters);
```

But this is the wrong way to do it.

```
        // array with fix column names
        var aColumnData = [{
            columnId: "Key"
        }, {
            columnId: "Value"
        }];

        //var aData = this.getModel().getData("/shrhelpSet").filter(oFilters);

        var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        oModel2.setData({
            columns: aColumnData,
            rows: aData
        });

        oTable.setModel(oModel2);

        oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
            var sColumnId = context.getObject().columnId;
            //alert(sColumnId);
            return new sap.ui.table.Column({
                id : sColumnId,
                label: sColumnId,
                template: sColumnId
            });
        });
        oTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

Comment: Does the binding work? Do you want to filter the binding in order that not all data is shown or do you want to remove the data from your model that doesn't match the filter completely?

Comment: I want to filter the binding that not all data is shown. At the moment i really dont understand how to give aData my row data for the table that is in /shrhelpSet after filtering it

Comment: The binding is working, its responsible that not all data is shown in the dropdown. And this data i want now to have in a table, i have the column, but the rows are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the filters to the binding of the rows aggregation like you did before with the items aggregation of the input.

```
oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(oFilters);
```

This has to be done *after* the last line of your snippet (after the rows are bound).

Comment: Do you also know why this is not working var aData = this.getModel().read("/shrhelpSet");
Here is my row data

Comment: I think its right, but the array is empty. Than i have a problem with my data source
{abort: ƒ}
abort: ƒ ()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 0
name: "abort"
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: VM27:2852
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
__proto__: Object

Comment: The read method of an odata model returns an object with an abort function, not the data. you need a success handler in which you handle the received data. Have a look at the documentation and/or open a new question if you need further help. Cheers https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/read

Comment: I made now a success handler. This is always the way i am doing it, und it returns me again a object
   var oTestModel = this.getModel();
   oTestModel.read("/shrhelpSet", {
    success: function(oData, oResponse){
     console.log("/shrhelpSet: " + oData);
    },

Comment: I forgot      var oDatas2 = oData;
     var test1 = oDatas2.results;
but i have a empty result